# Insert value in textarea using VBA excel

Tags: html, vba, textarea

I am trying to input value via vba excel

website have following code:

`<textarea name="query" rows="3" cols="44"></textarea>`

trying to input value in this textarea via vba excel

following all vba code are not working

`doc.querySelector("query").innerHTML = "welcome"`
`doc.querySelector("query").value = "welcome"`

`doc.querySelectorall("query").innerHTML = "welcome"`
`doc.querySelectorall("query").value = "welcome"`

can anyone guide

Thank you in advance

Comment: `.querySelector("[name=query]")`, or `"[name='query']"`, or... -- Possibly, setup a CSS selector

Comment: What has this question got to do with VB.NET? You say you want to use VBA yet I se no VBA tag, but there is a VB.NET tag when it's irrelevant. Read the tag descriptions and use the relevant tags and ONLY the relevant tags.

Comment: Thank Jmcihinnery. I changed the tag to VBA

Comment: "not working" doesn't tell us much about the exact error or problem you're having when you tried that code.

Comment: run time error: #91 Object variable or with block variable not set .  I tried below code  
 ```doc.querySelector("[name=query]") = "welcome"```

Comment: `doc.querySelector("[name=query]").value = "welcome"`

Comment: Maybe it's simpler if you specify an ID, e.g., `<TextArea id="ID1" ...>`, then it's just `doc.querySelector("#ID1").value = "welcome"` -- There's nothing related to VBA here, BTW